# How to add row number while printing

Tags: python, shelve

Here's a function I created for challenge 7.2 in Dawson book, but wanted to modify it a little bit. To not spam I'm sending just key place as other is not related to the problem.

```
def results(score):  
     name = input("What's your name? ")
     s = shelve.open("results.dat")
     s[str(score)] = [name]
     s.sync()
     scores = list(s.keys())
     scores.sort(reverse=True)
     print("Top 5 results in quiz game:\n")
     for i in scores[:5]:
         print("Points:", i, "Player:", "".join(s[i]))
     s.close()
```

My output looks:

```
Points: 8 player: Chris
Points: 6 player: klsjahd
Points: 5 player: dlahdlksjah
Points: 4 player: dnlsandlknasd
Points: 3 player: bleble
```

I'd want to add a row number, so I can show obvious thing like which top is it.

```
TOP 1: Points: 8 player: Chris
TOP 2: Points: 6 player: klsjahd
TOP 3: Points: 5 player: dlahdlksjah
TOP 4: Points: 4 player: dnlsandlknasd
TOP 5: Points: 3 player: bleble
```

Comment: Please take a moment to read [formatting help](/help/formatting). You can format a block of code by putting three backticks (`) on the lines before and after your code. Since you're new here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask] and how to provide a [mre]. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing the index in 'for' loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-for-loops)

Comment: Particularly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28072982/843953). See the `start` argument of `enumerate()`.

Comment: Yes, used new variable with value 1 then added += 1 after each loop, this fits perfectly for my current level. Thanks :)
and sorry for a mess